# Messaging Technology With Persistent Storage and Client Registry

Tags: database, networking, server

Is there a server-technology that provides a continuous stream of entries to an arbitrary number of listening clients (APIs should be available for many programming languages, preferably through a binary protocol)? Unlike some messaging/broker-technology like RabbitMQ I'd have the following requirements:

- The entries delivered MUST be persisted and MUST never be purged (unlike a traditional message queue that removes messages once they were consumed)
- The technology should provide a registration mechanism for listeners. Once listeners have registered, the server technology should maintain state of events that were successfully pushed to the registered listeners.
- If a listener reconnects all entries that haven't been consumed by the reconnecting listener MUST be pushed, so that there is a guarantee that EACH registered listener receives EACH persisted message (at least) once.